# Christian is $3$ times as old as Marie. Marie is $12$ years younger - Is there a simple method for elementary school student?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, word-problem

**Christian is 3 times as old as Marie. Marie is $12$ years younger than Christian. How old is Christian?**

The method that I know requires $2$ variables and $2$ equations.

\begin{align}C &= 3M \\                      
M &= C - 12 \end{align}

Substitute first equation into second equation and solve

\begin{align}M &= 3M - 12\\
12 &= 2M \\
M &= 6 \text{ years} \\
C &= 3M ( 3 \times 6 ) = 18\text{ years}\end{align}

**Is there a simpler way to explain this to a $5$th grader?**

He still hasn't learned math equations with $2$ variables or how to substitute first equation into second equation.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would consider the picture below:

Drawing $3$ blocks for age of Christian an a single block for the age of Marie.

[image]

Marie is $12$ years younger, so each block represent $6$ years.

Hence, Marie is $6$ years old and Christina is $3\times 6=18$ years old.

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution.I was hoping there is an age appropriate method.This really helps.

Comment: you are welcome. glad it helps.

Answer (score 0):

One idea that comes to mind is making a list of ages that are twelve years apart and then seeing which pair is the first to have one age be three times the other, like this:
$$\begin{array}{c|lcr}
\text{Marie's age} & \text{Christian's age} \\
\hline
1 & \qquad\ \ \ 13 \\
2 & \qquad\ \ \ 14 \\
3 & \qquad\ \ \ 15 \\
4 & \qquad\ \ \ 16 \\
5 & \qquad\ \ \ 17 \\
6 & \qquad\ \ \ 18
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose Marie were $\,1\,$ year old. Then Christian would be $\,3 \cdot 1 = 3\,$ years old, and the difference between their ages would be $\,3 - 1 = \color{blue}{2}\,$ years. *But* the actual difference is $\,12 = \color{red}{6} \cdot \color{blue}{2}\,$ years, so Marie must actually be $\,\color{red}{6} \cdot 1 = 6\,$ years old, and then Christian is $\,6\cdot 3 =18\,$.

The above obviously plays on the *linearity* of the problem, without spelling it out as such. It is important to teach that such tricks do ***not*** always work, yet elementary school students *can* quickly develop an intuition of sorts for linearity, even if it's not formally called by that name.

Answer (score 0):

Let $M$ be Marie's age.

We know Christian is $3$ times as old as Marie,
so Christian's age is $3M.$

But we also know Marie is $12$ years younger than Christian.
That is, $M = 3M - 12.$

Now you have an equation in one variable. Solve it.
That gives you $M.$ Then multiply by $3,$ because Christian's age is $3M.$

Of course you *can* assign a new symbol $C$ to represent Christian's age,
in addition to finding that Christian's age is $3M,$
if the additional symbol makes it easier for you to understand
the method of solving the problem.
But there is no *requirement* to assign such a symbol.